# Use IP Camera for Skype / Hangout?

Tags: skype, webcam, ip-camera, conferencing, google-hangouts

How can I use IP cameras (connected by Ethernet) for Google Hangout / Skype cameras?

I'd like to have the quality of those IP cameras and use them both as they were meant to and for Web Conference Video.

Any way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webcamoid seems to be an open source product that provides virtual camera's: https://webcamoid.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will create a virtual video device from an IP camera.

ManyCam for microsoft and mac

webcamstudio for linux

Comment: Hi, I will try ManyCam. Are there any Open source alternatives? Or portable?

Comment: For microsoft os'?
You could try SplitCam [http://www.splitcamera.com/]  It's free, not sure about opensource.